# Angular.js dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, angularjs

Только обучаюсь ангуляру, объясните разницу:

```
someApp.controller('someController', function($http){
   //что-то
});
```

и

```
someApp.controller('someController', ['$http', function($http){
   //что-то
}]);
```

Comment: В первом случае NG сам определяет зависимости, парся имена аргументов, во втором вы явно указываете, какие зависимости нужно подключить в качестве аргументов. Первый случай сломается при использовании минифкатора/обфускатора, второй нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй блок кода предохраняет от проблем обфускации кода при его минификации, например. Т.е. когда названия переменных изменяются Ангуляр, все равно будет правильно прозводить injection и определять, что первая переменная - это все-таки $http сервис, а не что-то другое. Ниже привожу пример до и после обфускации:

```
someApp.controller('someController', ['$http', function($http){
   $http.get().then(function(response){
       $scope.name = response.name;
   });
}]);

someApp.controller('someController', ['$http', function(b){
   b.get().then(function(a){
       s.name = a.name;
   });
}]);
```